# Output strings in LC-3

Tags: lc3

I am writing a short LC-3 program to ask the user to input their name and print it out.

It should be something like this......

```
What is your name?

abcd

Hi abcd, nice to meet you!
```

But I got this one in the output......

```
What is your name?

abcd

Hi abcd

, nice to meet you!
```

I created 2 .STRINGZ for the sentences,

"Hi " as String1 and ", have a good day." as Strings2,

but how can I put the sentence ", have a good day." after the user name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much to go on, some code would be nice (at least the relevant parts). However, just from what you posted... my guess would be that you are storing the characters as they are being entered, and at some point checking to see if one of those keystrokes is the "enter" key. It seems like you may be storing what's typed before checking for the enter key. Thus when the result is printed out, it's printing exactly what was typed, "abcd[enter]", which is causing the linefeed to print out also.

The easy solution is to move the piece of code where you check for the enter key before the code which stores what is entered, such that the enter key isn't stored also.

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful... but this is just my best guess based on the info given.